# Counter for inserted rows in PSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm looking for a PostgreSQL equivalent of the image below. I have a script to batch insert multiple tables, the idea is to declare some variables to count how many of each have been inserted when executing.

[image]

So far I have this, however there's no straightforward way for @@ROW_COUNT:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DO $$ 
DECLARE
   EmailModulesTotal            integer := 0;
   DependenciesTotal            integer := 0;
   ModuleTypesTotal             integer := 0;
   ModuleSectionsTotal          integer := 0;
BEGIN

-- inserts go here

  RAISE NOTICE 'Total Inserted/Updated Email Modules: %
  Total Inserted Dependencies: %
  Total Inserted Module Types: %
  Total Inserted Module Sections: %',
    EmailModulesTotal, 
    DependenciesTotal, 
    ModuleTypesTotal, 
    ModuleSectionsTotal
END $$;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: "there's no straightforward way for @@ROW_COUNT",  What about `SELECT count(*) FROM table;` ?

Comment: That wouldn't work because @@ROW_COUNT is used for counting the inserted rows of the previous statement; knowing the total rows from the table is different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PL/pgSQL you can access the number of affected (i.e. inserted in your case) rows using [get diagnostics](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS). Here is an illustration.

```sql
create temporary table t (id serial, txt text);

do language plpgsql
$$
declare
    counter integer;
begin
    insert into t(txt) values ('One'), ('Two'), ('Three');
    get diagnostics counter = row_count;
    raise notice 'Inserted % rows', counter;
end;
$$;
```

The result is `Inserted 3 rows`

Another way in plain SQL is to use a data modifying CTE:

```sql
with cte as
(
 insert into t(txt) values ('One'), ('Two'), ('Three')
 returning 1
)
select count(*) from cte;
```

Whichever suits you better.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Ended up doing this below every query (changing the counter variable):

GET DIAGNOSTICS v_RowCountInt = ROW_COUNT;
DependenciesTotal := DependenciesTotal + v_RowCountInt;